# Custom functions in Route laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have written a few functions in home controller.
Lets say the function is called data();
My route function looks like this :

```
Route::get('/example', function(){

"I want to use data() function/method here, is this possible ?"

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/example','yourcontollername@yourfunctionname');
```